# How to generate an unordered list from database table data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server

hi i have an unordered list `<ul><li><ul><li>`

I had made a table to fill the unordered list but how to fetch that data into `li` and `ul`
the table consists of home, organisation (with children as policy, employeesdetails), and so on..  How do i fill these `ul` and `li`'s and children of `li`'s with data from sqlserver2005 table?
I'm not supposed to use any asp.net built in controls like asp.net menu

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
        {      
            int currentDepth =  Convert.ToInt32(row["Depth"]);      
            if (lastDepth < currentDepth) 
            {
                output.Append("<ul class=\"dropdown\">");         
                numUL++ ;    
            }     
            else if (lastDepth > currentDepth) 
            {         
                output.Append("</li></ul></li>");         
                numUL--   ;  
            }     
            else if (lastDepth > -1) 
            {
                output.Append("</li>");     
            }      
            output.AppendFormat("<li class=\"depth-{1}\">{0}", row["ApplicationName"], currentDepth);      
            lastDepth = currentDepth; 
        }  
        for (int i = 1;i <= numUL;i++) 
        {     
            output.Append("</li></ul>"); 
        }    
        Literal1.Text = output.ToString();
```

i have made the navigation bar based on above code
my navbar looks like this

> Home|Organisation|Recruitment|Help|Issues

i am getting all the li's properly(like department and users under organisation) 
i have one prolem how do i get the urls dynamically to the above code

my table looks like this

```
ApplicationID    ApplicationName  ParentKey  Depth  URL  
1                 HOME             NULL      0      #   
2                 Organisation     NULL      0      #
3                 Department       2         1      #
4                 User             2         1      #  
5                 Issues           NULL      0      # 
6                 issuestrack      5         1      #
7                 Help             NULL      0      #
8                 helpneeded       7         1      #
```

thanx in advance

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me. Also could be better presented.

Comment: @dtech i have searched many sites..i have found them using Itreecategory or asp.net menu control,and other things wich im not supposed to use...so i finaly decided o post my qs here

Comment: Buy a book about web development in C# and ASP.net...

Comment: Post the schema of your table. Let us see how you are representing the hierarchy at the db level. Then we can discuss getting that up to your app where you can iterate through it and spit out the ul/li tags.

Answer (score 0):

[Building a Database Driven Hierarchical Menu using ASP.NET and SooperFish Jquery Plugin](http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/09/14/aspsooperfishmenu/)

Answer (score -1):

Try looking at the "for xml" clause for your select.  Since I agree that this looks like homework, you're going to have to do some digging yourself.  Good luck!